# Curdate between criteria changes every monday

Tags: mysql, date, unix-timestamp, between

I am trying to run a query which will return customer orders between `curdate() -interval 1 day` AND `curdate()` for all 4 working days, but every Monday the criteria should be `curdate() - interval 3 days` AND `curdate().`

I am unable to find an example and my current code is

```
(cast(from_unixtime(`schedule`.`last_change_timestamp`) as date)  
            BETWEEN (curdate() - interval 3 day) AND (curdate())
```

and I change it to 1 from Tuesday and every Monday change the `- interval to 3` again. Would like to automate this process please.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
(
   (      DAY_OF_WEEK(CURDATE()) = 2 
      AND cast(FROM_UNIXTIME(schedule.last_change_timestamp) as date)
            BETWEEN (curdate() - interval 3 day) AND (curdate() - interval 1 day)
   )
   OR
   (      DAY_OF_WEEK(CURDATE()) != 2 
      AND cast(FROM_UNIXTIME(schedule.last_change_timestamp) as date)
            = (curdate() - interval 1 day)
   )
)
```

The formatting of the parentheses is not what I would use in real code, but for the sake of demonstration hopefully it makes it clearer.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek

Note that you haven't specified what you want to happen on weekends, so I'm assuming it is irrelevant and have lumped them together with Tues-Fri.

Comment: Dear Peter, The code works fine but I don't want to include current date in the output, Last 3 days if it is Monday and Yesterday if it is Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday or Friday. When i executed my code today it gives me data for 20, 21,22 and 23. What am I doing wrong ??

Comment: The `between` operator is inclusive. So on each line instead of saying "BETWEEN ... AND curdate()" you should say "BETWEEN ... AND (curdate() - interval 1 day)".

Comment: If you are using this answer, please mark it as the answer. I'm trying to get reputation points and if you don't mark the answer then I get nada...